# PHP: Non-Repeating Selection From an Array

Tags: php, arrays, random

In my php script, I have a variable $data that contains an array that may have various number of elements.

The script picks one of the array elements at random and outputs it to the browser:

```
# count number of elements in $data
$n = count($data);

# pick a random number out of the number of elements in $data
$rand = rand(0, ($n - 1));

# output a random element
echo '<p> . trim($data[$rand]) . '</p>';
```

QUESTION: I want to improve that script, so that it doesn't output the same array element again until it runs out of array elements. For example, if an array contains elements numbered 0 to 9, and the script picked an array element #4, I want it to remember that, and next time the script runs, to exclude the element that was #4.

It could probably be done in many different ways, but I'm looking for the simplest and most elegant solution, and would be grateful for help from a PHP expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the numbers that were already picked in the user's session.

```
session_start();
$n = count($data); 

// If the array isn't initialized, or we used all the numbers, reset the array
if( !isset( $_SESSION['used_nums']) || count( $_SESSION['used_nums']) == $n) {
    $_SESSION['used_nums'] = array();
}

do{ 
    $rand = rand(0, ($n - 1));
} while( isset( $_SESSION['used_nums'][$rand]));

echo '<p>' . trim($data[$rand]) . '</p>';    
$_SESSION['used_nums'][$rand] = 1;
```

---

Or, perhaps a more clever way, using [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) and [`array_rand`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
session_start();
$n = count($data); 

// If the array isn't initialized, or we used all the numbers, reset the array
if( !isset( $_SESSION['used_nums']) || count( $_SESSION['used_nums']) == $n) {
    $_SESSION['used_nums'] = array();
}

$unused = array_intersect_key( $data, $_SESSION['used_nums'];
$rand = array_rand( $unused);

echo '<p>' . trim($unused[$rand]) . '</p>';    
$_SESSION['used_nums'][$rand] = 1;
```

Comment: For the second example, you would need to echo `trim($unused[$rand])`

Answer (score 2):

You could shuffle the array and then simply iterate over it:

```
shuffle($data);
foreach ($data as $elem) {
    // …
}
```

If you don’t want to alter the array order, you could simply shuffle the array’s keys:

```
$keys = array_keys($data);
shuffle($keys);
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    // $data[$key]
}
```

Comment: This still leaves the possibility of having the same index twice.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Why do you think so?

Comment: Because OP wants a random, unique index selected each page load.

Comment: Probably there's a way not only to shuffle the order, but also unset the one that has been chosen? Would that work?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Ok, missed the point that he wanted to maintain the state among multiple script runs.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov You could do the same with the shuffled array keys, store it in a more persistent storage, and remove the key from the array when displayed.

Comment: Mmm... why didn't I think of that. Good idea, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions to store the indexes you've used so far. Try this.

```
session_start();

$used = &$_SESSION['usedIndexes'];

// used all of our array indexes
if(count($used) > count($data)) 
    $used = array();

// remove the used indexes from data
foreach($used as $index)
    unset($data[$index]);

$random = array_rand($data);

// append our new index to used indexes
$used[] = $random;

echo '<p>', trim($data[$random]) ,'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$selection=$x[$randomNumber];
unset($x[$randomNumber]);
```